# How to count and add only duplicate value in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array with some duplicates value. i want to count only duplicate values like
`array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,4,1];`
and the expected output is = 2

Comment: Did you try it yourself ?
If so then show the code and the issue you facing.

Answer (score 2):

A concise variant if you need a count of all duplicate elements. May be faster than looping with duplicate check:

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,4,1];
const dupCount = array.length - new Set(array).size;
console.log(dupCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to make a set that has property names that refer to your values:

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 1];

const duplicatesSet = array1.reduce((set, value, index) => {
  // if an entry has an index nearer the end of the list,
  // we know it is a duplicate
  if (array1.lastIndexOf(value) !== index)
    set.add(value);
  return set;
}, new Set());
console.log("Duplicates Set:", [...duplicatesSet.values()]); // show the set
console.log("Duplicates count:", duplicatesSet.size); // output set size
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

```
function countDuplicate(array){ // array to check
array.sort();// sort it so that if value is duplicated it is presented right to it
var count = 0;
for(let i =0; i<array.length; i++){
    let j = i+1;
    while( j< array.length && array[j] == array[i]){// iterate all same value
        j++;
    }
    if(j-i>1){ //if you  have atleast one same value increase the count
        count++;
    }
    i = j -1;// here we are subtracting one because one is increment by for loop
}
return count;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array by ones that match but don't have the same index as the current item. That'll make a new array and you can just output the length of that?

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,4,1]

const duplicates = arr.filter((item, i) => i !== arr.indexOf(item))
const count = duplicates.length

console.log(duplicates) // Output: [ 4, 1 ]
console.log(count) // Output: 2
```

It can be a one-liner like

```js
arr.filter((item, i) => i !== arr.indexOf(item)).length
```